# Automatically set execute permission for downloaded executables from known sources

Tags: permissions, security, downloads

If I understand correctly, Ubuntu would only set read and write permissions for files downloaded from the internet because `umask` is applied to the files. Is there a way for files to have execute permissions when they are downloaded from trusted sources, say an internal server? Typically these files are archived as .zip.

Comment: Why would you want a .zip archive to be executable?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say binaries which are bundle in an archive when unzipped only have rw permissions. Now executable. I want these binaries to have x permissions by default when downloaded and unzipped.

Comment: Now that's an entirely different question and has nothing to do with the downloading, but only with how the archive was zipped and gets unzipped again. Zip archives preserve permissions by default, so if the binaries had Linux executable permission set when they were archived, these will be restored automatically.

Comment: Possibly one could write a script that unzips the archive and then checks all files for their type and make ELF files and scripts executable, but that might not always be desirable and is prone to errors. I might look into that later or tomorrow if you want that.

Comment: I see. I didn't know Zip archives preserve permissions. We have a build system which archives (using groovy scripts) our executables and puts it in a server. I thought that Ubuntu changes these permissions on download. In that case, I think I should be able to configure permissions in the groovy script. This is my hunch.